# Accessing Tomcat Context Path from Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

In my Servlet I would like to access the root of the context so that I can do some JavaScript minifying.

It would be possible to do the minify as part of the install process but I would like to do it on Servlet startup to reduce the implementation cost.

Does anyone know of a method for getting the context directory so that I can load and write files to disk?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should give you the real path that you can use to extract / edit files.

[Javadoc Link](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String))

We're doing something similar in a context listener.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(final ServletConfig config) {
        final String context = config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I was after.

I suspect this is what wrumsby was shooting for in his answer.Thanks guys. The quality of content on this site continues to impress me.

Answer (score 2):

> *In my Servlet I would like to access the root of the context so that I can do some JavaScript minifying*

You can also access the files in the WebContent by [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29). So if your JS file is for example located at `WebContent/js/file.js` then you can use the following in your `Servlet` to get a `File` handle of it:

```
File file = new File(getServletContext().getResource("/js/file.js").getFile());
```

or to get an `InputStream`:

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/js/file.js");
```

That said, how often do you need to minify JS files? I have never seen the need for request-based minifying, it would only unnecessarily add much overhead. You probably want to do it only once during application's startup. If so, then using a `Servlet` for this is a bad idea. Better use [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and do your thing on `contextInitialized()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was googling the result and getting no where. In JSP pages that need to use Java Script to access the current *contextPath* it is actually quite easy.

Just put the following lines into your *html head* inside a `script` block.

```
// set up a global java script variable to access the context path
var contextPath = "${request.contextPath}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(final ServletConfig config) {
        final String context = config.getServletContext();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Or something more complex?

Comment: This might be the right path but I don't think it gets me all of the way there. I still need to be able to open files that are in the context directory.