# How do I get root network path in JSP?

Tags: jsp

Simply put, how do I retrieve the root network path in JSP?

If the page is located at http://mysite.com/Level1/index.html and the context path is /Level1 (where the forward slash is the root), then the root network path should be mysite.com.  How do I retrieve this in JSP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`getServerName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29).

So in JSP : `${pageContext.request.serverName}`

Answer (score 2):

Servlets (and thus JSPs) have access to ServletRequest and ServletContext objects, which have the necessary meta data for getting the resources and location for your servlet.

**ServletRequest**

It appears you only need the server name - then, as the other posts indicate, the ServletRequest can give you that - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

**ServletContext (not directly useful in your case)**

Remember that JSPs are simply servlets - your JSP has access to the Servlet Context and the Servlet Request objects.

The ServletContext offers you an API for accessing the information about where its running (on disk) and how its resources are located, and this is called the **servlet context.**

The servlet context has a method "getResourcePaths" (useful for finding files in your servlet directory), and ***"getRealPath()"*** (which gives you the "full" path to the servlet, including hostname).

See [Accessing Tomcat Context Path from Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537/accessing-tomcat-context-path-from-servlet)

Comment: No, this isn't right.  `getRealPath()` returns the path on local disk, and has nothing to do with the request URL.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the `serverName` property of the `ServletRequest` object (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29)).

In JSP EL, `${pageContext.request.serverName}` should work.  In a scriptlet, use `request.getServerName()`