# How to support variable context path?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to write a webapp, using Jetty. My context path is decided externally and will vary from one customer to the next.

Is this a normal requirment?

Assuming I have links to other pages, AJAX calls from static JavaScript files and image references from static CSS files, how can this be achieved? What is the recommended project structure?

Can I accomplish this without templates? (JSP).

Comment: So you're saying you'll be deploying the same webapp multiple times in the same container, under different names?

Comment: Looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/57595/354831) ?

Comment: Use the `<c:url>` tag? What do you mean, "without templates"? How do you create the view?

Comment: Here is the example of how to add external references in JSP **without hard-coding context path**: [Adding external CSS in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14571407/814702)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a normal requirment?

Yes. Nothing in your webapp should depend on the value of the context path.

It's actually quite simple to support any context path: systematically prepend the context path to every URL your app produces.

In JSP files, use the `<c:url>` tag (or similar) to generate URLs.

In JS files, use URLs passed from the JSP pages, or use a global variable set in theJSP file and containing the context path to generate the URLs.

In Java files, use `request.getContextPath()` to get the context path and prepend it to URLs.

In CSS files, use relative paths.